# Error in Adding product in product grid admin panel: Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-grid

I am trying to create the "Add Product" grid in admin panel in my custom module. I managed to create the grid and the Add product button is also getting displayed.

The issue here is on clicking the Add product button I am getting some JS errors and the page reloads without any of the products being added in the grid.

The error I am facing is,

```
configure.js:326 POST admin/sales/template/loadBlock/key/9d1f4989a90d8933aea24fc9668fe432525b25d15d53b442a03d0b5c5b89b12d/block/search,items,shipping_method,totals,giftmessage,billing_method?isAjax=true 404 (Forbidden)
```

How can I add the products in the product grid in my custom module.
 Please can anyone help me with the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please run the following commands,

php bin/magento setup:upgrade and then 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Make sure you have provided proper permission for folders and files.
If this doesn't work, it would be better you post your xml file here, kept in the view/adminhtml/ui_component folder of your module.

Thanks.